# How to implement continuous delivery on a platform consisting of multiple applications which all depends on one database and each other?

Tags: database, architecture, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci

We are working on old project which consists of multiple applications which all use the same database and strongly depend on each other. Because of the size of the project, we can't refactor the code so they all use the API as a single database source. The platform contains the following applications:

- Website
- Admin / CMS
- API
- Cronjobs

Right now we want to start implementing a CI/CD pipeline using Gitlab. We are currently experiencing problems, because we can't update the database for the deployment of one application without breaking all other applications (unless we deploy all applications).

I was thinking about a solution where one pipeline triggers all other pipelines. Every pipeline will execute all newly added database migrations and will test if the pipeline is still working like it should. If all pipelines succeeds, the deployment of all applications will be started.

I'm doubting if this is a good solution, because this change will only increase the already high coupling between our applications. Does anybody know a better solution how to implement CI/CD for our platform?

Answer (score 3):

You have to stop thinking about these as separate applications. You have a monolith with multiple modules, but until they can be decoupled, they are all one application and will have to deployed as such.

Fighting this by pretending they aren't is likely a waste of time, your efforts would be better spent actually decoupling these systems.

Comment: Well we are thinking about a plan to start decoupling our modules, but until this is done, we want to find a way that we can cut down the time we spend on deployment. Maybe we can start working on a script which will deploy everything together after someone presses on a button, so we can still decide when to deploy everything. The script can be build in a way so we can later on re-use the script to deploy single modules (when we decoupled our application). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are likely a lot of solutions, but one that I've done in the past is create a separate repository for the CI/CD of the entire system.

Each individual repo builds that component, and then you can create tags as they are released or ready for CI at a system level.

The separate CI/CD repo pulls in the appropriate tags for each item and runs CI/CD against all of them as one unit.  This allows you to specify which tag for each repo you want to specify, which should prevent this pipeline from failing when changes are made on the individual components.

Comment: So there is one repo which consists of all 4 modules and it will test the application as a whole every time someone pushes a commit to one of these modules? When this test succeeds, we can deploy all modules?

Comment: Yes, that's one option. I was also suggesting you could make 5 separate repos...one for each individual module and then 1 that pulls down the other 4 and tests them together.  But it largely depends how interconnected they are.

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself ***why*** these "distinct applications" are using "one and the same database".  Is that because every single one of all of those "distinct applications" all deal with "one and the same business semantics" ?  If so, as Rob already stated, then you simply have one single application (and on top of that, there ***will be no decoupling*** precisely because your business semantics are singular/atomic/...).

Or are there discernable portions in the db structure such that a highly accurate mapping could be identified saying "this component uses that portion" etc. etc. ?  In that case what is it that causes you to say stuff like "can't update the database for the deployment of ..." ???  (BTW "update the database" is not the same thing as "restructure the database".  Please, please, ***please*** be ***precise***.)  The answer to that will identify what you've got to tackle.

Comment: I think you're correct when you're saying it is the same single application. But all modules have their own git repository, so I'm not sure how we can automatically deploy one module when someone pushes a commit to the repository, without running into problems because of dependencies to each other and to the same database.